# Python can't load modules from a large zipfile

Tags: python

I've been packing up a script and some resources into a executable zipfile using the technique in (for example) [this blog post](http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/10/bundling-python-files-into-stand-alone.html)

The process suddenly stopped working, and I think it has to do with the zip64 extension. When I try to run the executable zipfile I get:

/usr/bin/python: can't find '**main**' module in '/path/to/my_app.zip'

I believe that the only change is that one of the resource files (a disk image) has gotten larger. I've verified that `__main__.py` is still in the root of the archive. The size of the zipfile used to be 600MB, and is now 2.5GB. I noticed in the [zipimport docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) the following statement:

> ZIP archives with an archive comment are currently not supported.

Reading through [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) on the zipfile format I see that:

> The .ZIP file format allows for a comment containing up to 65,535 bytes of data to occur at the end of the file after the central directory.[25]

And later, regarding **zip64**:

> In essence, it uses a "normal" central directory entry for a file, followed by an optional "zip64" directory entry, which has the larger fields.[29]

Inferring a bit, it sounds like this might be what's happening: my zipfile has grown to require the zip64 extension. The zip64 extension data is stored in the comment section so now there is an active comment section, and python's `zipimport` is refusing to read my zipfile.

Can anyone provide guidance on:

1. verifying the cause of why python can't find `__main__.py` in my zipfile
2. providing any workaround

Note that the image file has always been 16GB in size, however it used to only occupy 600MB on the disk (it resides on an ext4 filesystem, if that matters). It now occupies > 7GB on disk. From the wikipedia page:

> The original .ZIP format had a 4 GiB limit on various things (uncompressed size of a file, compressed size of a file and total size of the archive)

I build the zipfile using a python script so in order to try and work around this issue, I add the python code to the zipfile before adding the image file. The thought being that python might simply ignore the comment section and see a valid zipfile that contains the python code but not the large image file. This doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the python source code, in zipimport.c, we can see that indeed it looks for the `end-of-central-directory` block in the last 22 bytes of the file. It does not retract the search from there if it doesn't find a valid end-of-central-directory (and I guess that makes it not a compliant zip parser). In any case, what it does do is it looks at the offset and size of the central directory reported in the end-of-central-directory record. `offset + size` should be the location of the end-of-central-directory record. If it is not, it computes the difference between the actual and expected location and adds this offset to all offsets in the central directory. This means that python supports loading modules from a zipfile which is catted to the end of another file.

It appears, however, that the zipimport implementation for 2.7.6 (distributed with ubuntu 14.04) is broken for large zipfiles (greater than > 2GB? I think max signed 32-bit long). It works, however for python 3.4.3 (also distributed with ubuntu 14.04). zipimport.c has changed sometime between 2.7.6 and 2.7.12, so it may work for newer python 2's.

My solution is to pack a resource zip, and a code zip, then cat them together, and run the app with python3 instead of python2. I write the offset and size of the resource zip to a metadata file in the code zip. The code uses this information and `filechunkio` to get a `zipfile.ZipFile` for the resource zip segment of the packfile.

Not a great solution, but it works.